# Embedding TFS Build badge on Github README.md does not work

Tags: github, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to show my TFS Build badge on my README.md page but it does not seem work\render correctly. The build may have failed but I still just get a thin yellow line appearing. If I enter the badge url into the browser it appears correctly.

This is how I'm trying to embed...

/_apis/public/build/definitions/bb3fac12-6683-46b2-9395-30741fa345b0/41/badge" alt="Project Badge" width="1000">

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Your image is not showing up.

Comment: I am wondering if it is because it is an onprem TFS? Could the fact that GitHub uses Camo be my problem and is there a way around this?  https://help.github.com/articles/about-anonymized-image-urls/

Comment: Where did you host it? If it has some sensitive info, try to censor it.

Comment: http://mydomain.local:8080/tfs/project/_apis/public/build/definitions/bb3fac12-6683-46b2-9395-30741fa345b0/41/badge

Comment: Take a screenshot and host it somewhere. The file is only visible to you (`mydomain.local:8080`)

Comment: I don't mind if the badge is only visible when viewing the github page from the domain. Therefore, I should be able to do this. I still think the GitHub Cam url proxy is causing my problem.

Comment: [This is what I'm talking about](https://postimg.org/image/4n7pye7csr/)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot about how does it not work? And can your TFS server be accessed from internet?